# Regarding admin panel of website error 500 and script error / symfony error

Tags: php, symfony

I had my website hosted on a2hosting and operating ecommerce website with platform prestashop. How while performing regular task of clear cache from performance tab under administration section of admin panel. Suddenly my admin panel is not accessible. My hosting provider gave following remark 
However, as a courtesy, we have taken a look and can see that the site www.asiauvsaa.com/asiauvsaa-prestashop has a script error.

> [message] => Uncaught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent parameter "mailer_user". in /home/asiauvsa/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php:102

You will need to resolve that to correct the 500. In regards to the main URL. That issue appears to be due to a misconfigured `.htaccess` file. It then tries to resolve to https://www.asiauvsaa.com/en/ which doesn't exist.

not been able identify and rectify the error so i can have access to my admin panel.

Regards
Minesh Shah

Answer (score 0):

**message] => Uncaught Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\ParameterNotFoundException: You have requested a non-existent parameter "mailer_user". in /home/asiauvsa/public_html/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ParameterBag/ParameterBag.php:102**

This error usually occurs when you didnt defined the **mailer_user** parameter in parameter.yml file . Bcz Swift Mailer uses this parameter to configure emails. Just add this param in parameter.yml file and clear cache again . Hopefully this will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have `%mailer_user%` somewhere into configuration of your project, but you didn't have provided value for this parameter.

You basically have 3 ways to provide it:

1. Simplest way is to add value for this parameter into `parameters` section of your `services.yaml`
2. If this parameter is defined into your own configuration file - you can change it to `%env(MAILER_USER)%` and define value of `MAILER_USER` as environment variable (either natural environment variable or by using `.env.local` file)
3. Hardest, but still possible way is to create [`CompilerPass`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html) to provide value of this parameter into DI container.

Please check Symfony documentation about [configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html) in a case if you need more information

**UPDATE:**
Answer given above refers to Symfony 4, for Symfony 2 and 3 you have to provide value of your parameter through `parameters.yml` file.